# Does every null set have a superset which is an $F_{\sigma}$ null set?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue null set in $\mathbb R$. Can we find a set $B$ with the following properties:

1) $A \subset B$

2) $B$ has measure $0$

3) $B$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set (i.e. a countable union of closed sets).

I suppose so because that null sets I had ever seen have been constructed from finite or countable sets or Cantor set.

Comment: The role of $A$ is not clear. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The question appears to be: Is it the case that for every $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ where $A$ has Lebesgue measure zero, $A$ has a superset that is a countable union of closed sets that each has Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, that's what i want to say, thank you

Comment: @SergeyKopylov I have completely re-written the question and the title. If I have made a mistake please let know. In that case I will bring back the original version.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer, perhaps surprisingly, is **no**. You write

> null sets I had ever seen have been constructed from finite or countable sets or Cantor set

But that doesn't exhaust the full variety of the null sets at all. There are quite a lot of very strange null sets out there, and one of the most important examples (and a counterexample to many seemingly-plausible claims) is the existence of a **[comeager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set) null set** - that is, a null set whose complement is the union of countably many nowhere-dense sets. At first glance such a thing may seem impossible, but they do exist - e.g. take the set of all non-absolutely-normal numbers.

(See e.g. the discussion at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43478/is-there-a-measure-zero-set-which-isnt-meagre). Basically, *category* and *measure* are completely orthogonal, although they're both "notions of size," and the interplay between the two (and other notions of size) gives rise to a lot of interesting analysis, topology, and descriptive set theory.)

By the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), comeager null sets can't be covered "efficiently" by $F_\sigma$ sets. Specifically, BCT implies that (in $\mathbb{R}$) meager $G_\delta$ sets are nowhere dense, so comeager $F_\sigma$ sets contain intervals and hence aren't null. So any comeager null $A$ gives a counterexample to your guess.

Answer (score 5):

A closed set of Lebesgue measure zero has empty interior. So a countable union of such sets, an $F_\sigma$ of measure zero, is meager (also  called "first Baire category), and so are all its subsets. But there are Lebesgue null sets that are not meager, for example the set of those numbers in $[0,1]$ whose binary expansion does not have asymptotically half zeros and half ones (i.e., those numbers whose binary expansions violate the strong law of large numbers).