# Properties about the comeagre null sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is non-Borel

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

I have learnt from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3179514/does-every-null-set-have-a-superset-which-is-an-f-sigma-null-set) that comeagre null sets (sets with Lebesgue measure zero whose complement is a countable union of nowhere dense sets) do exist, and they cannot be included in $F_\sigma$ null sets. It seems that being comeagre means that a set is "big", and being null means that a set is "small". I would like to learn more about such kind of sets.

So my questions are:

(a) Does there exist a comeagre null set which is non-Borel?

(b) Is it true that: if $E$ is a comeagre null set that is non-Borel, $B$ is a Borel subset of $E$, then $E\setminus B$ does not have a superset which is a $F_\sigma$ null set?

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**: As stated in the comment, there exists a comeagre null set by a cardinality argument. It is standard that there are $\mathfrak{c}$ Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Pick any comeagre null set $E_0$, let $C$ be the standard Cantor set, then $E_0\setminus C$ is a comeagre null set disjoint with $C$, and for any set $S\subset C$ we have $(E_0\setminus C)\cup S$ being comeagre null. So there are $2^\mathfrak{c}$ comeagre null sets. This shows that (a) is true.

If we take $E_0$ to be Borel (take the standard construction for example), $S\subset C$ to be non-Borel, then $E = (E_0\setminus C)\cup S$ is non-Borel, but $C$ is a $F_\sigma$ null set that is a superset of $E \setminus (E_0\setminus C) = S$. This shows that (b) is false.

Comment: If you don't get an answer straight away, this is probably hard enough for Math Overflow.

Comment: A great little book: *Measure and Category* by John C. Oxtoby.  See if your library has it!

Comment: See if you can prove:  there are $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ Borel sets, but there are $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ comeager null sets in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ChrisSanders Yes, but good answers take time, so I'll wait :)

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, that's great hint. It is standard that there are $\mathfrak{c}$ Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Pick any comeagre null set $E$, let $C$ be the standard Cantor set, then $E\setminus C$ is a comeagre null set disjoint with $C$, and for any set $S\subset C$ we have $(E\setminus C)\cup S$ being comeagre null. So there are $2^\mathfrak{c}$ comeagre null sets. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, "$F_{\sigma}$ null" $\implies$ "meager and null" (simultaneously), but not conversely. See [this 1 May 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/ZBCCYjtCSMA/m/19OUtU88RwAJ) and my answer to [Jordan measure zero discontinuities a necessary condition for integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/870108/13130). Incidentally, while "$F_{\sigma}$ null" sets are small in the sense of measure and category, the 3rd paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4424369/13130) **(continued)**

Comment: shows that such a set can have Hausdorff dimension $1$ in every nonempty open interval (a much stronger "largeness condition" than continuum many points in every nonempty open interval). **Note:** In my previous comment, "not conversely" of course is obvious because one simply picks a "meager and null" set that is not $F_{\sigma}.$ What I meant is that there exists a "meager and null" set that is not the subset of any "$F_{\sigma}$ null" set (or even any countable union of "$F_{\sigma}$ null" sets, although this additional strengthening is automatic).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for your information!